# Can a Gazer Familiar use its Eye Rays?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, familiars

Given that, from [Find Familiar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar):

> A familiar can't attack, but it can take other actions as normal.

Can a Gazer Familiar ([VGM, p. 126](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/gazer-familiar); [WDH, p. 105](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/wdh/spring-madness#X13ThorvinsWorkshop)) use its Eye Rays?

> ***Eye Rays.*** The gazer shoots two of the following magical eye rays at random (reroll duplicates), choosing one or two targets it can see within 60 feet of it:

The rays aren't listed as attacks, so I lean on "yes, it can". On the other hand, it seems much more powerful than other familiar forms.

---

I am not sure if the Gazer Variant found in *Volo's Guide to Monsters* (page 126) behaves the same as the familiar Gazer in *Waterdeep: Dragon Heist* (page 105). If there are differences between them, an ideal answer would cover that as well.

Comment: The reason that it is in the W:DH is that the published adventures always add in any monster that is not in the MM, PHB, or DMG.  Either new monsters, NPC's, or custome monsters, or monsters from other books.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Yes: variant familiars behave as NPCs that serve the caster

> A gazer serving as a familiar has the following trait.
>   **Familiar**. The gazer can serve another creature as a familiar, forming a
>   telepathic bond with its willing master, provided that the mater{sic}
>   is at least a 3rd level spell caster (VGTM: p. 126)

This familiar is not summoned with a spell, just as other variant familiars are not summoned with a spell, and as such are not bound by the spell's restrictions.  As with the pseudodragon and the imp variant familiars, they are more powerful than the summoned ones in a lot of ways, but if they are killed cannot be resummoned with the spell.

Related questions [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101217/why-cant-the-variant-imp-familiar-be-found-with-the-find-familiar-spell?rq=1), and [over here.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/100110/22566)

Comment: Oh, so it could even use its Bite attack?

Comment: @BlueMoon93 Yes, it is an NPC/monster, not a fey spirit taking the form of X.

Comment: The second paragraph with the text supporting it would answer the other Gazer question by the same OP.

Comment: @Eternallord66 I agree, but I'll hold off on that one until I can re read W:DH and make sure I "grok" that question.

Comment: @Upper_Case Hmm, that's weird.  Let me try again.